# Cannot get value from state - React

Tags: reactjs, ethereum

Hey this is my code and I want to print the networkType but it is not priniting out anything this code was working in App.js but not in home.js.

I created a class component in home.js

**Home.js**:

```
import {Component, React} from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Web3 from 'web3';
class Home extends Component
{
    state={
        person : [
          {networkType:'None'}
        ]
    }
    
    componentDidMount()
    {
        this.loadBlockchainData();
    }
    
    async loadBlockchainData()
    {
        const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || "https://localhost:8545");
        const network = await web3.eth.net.getNetworkType();
        this.setState(
            {
                person:[
                    {networkType:network}
                ]
            }
        )
    }
    render()
    {
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Hello</h1>
                <h1>Network is: {this.state.networkType}</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Home;
```

Comment: Try to check your console logs and make sure you recieve the data (do some print debugging).

Comment: yep I got the solution the moment after I posted this xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just update like this:

```
this.state.person[0].networkType
```